# NVCC register usage report in __device__ function

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvcc, ptxas

I'm trying to get some information about register usage in my *CUDA* kernels using *NVCC* option
 `--ptxas-options=v` and while with global functions everything is ok, I'm having some difficulties with the device ones since the

`ptxas info    : Used N registers`

line is missing in the output. I tried to use the noinline keyword and to keep them in another file, with respect to the calling global function, since I thought that *NVCC* was reporting the full register usage of the global function including the called device ones after the inline but nothing changes. I can get the information about register usage of the device functions only defining them as global.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As I understand it, `ptxas` (the device assembler) only outputs a register count on code which it links. Standalone `__device__` functions are not linked by the assembler, they are only compiled. Therefore, the assembler won't emit a register count value for device functions. I don't believe there is a workaround for this.

However, it is still possible to get the register footprint of a  `__device__` function by dumping the elf data from the assembler output using  `cuobjdump`. You can do this as follows:

```
$ cat vdot.cu
__device__  __noinline__ float vdot(float v1, float v2) {
    return (v1 * v2);
}

__device__ __noinline__  float vdot(float2 v1, float2 v2) {
    return (v1.x * v2.x) + (v1.y * v2.y);
}

__device__ __noinline__ float vdot(float4 v1, float4 v2) {
    return (v1.x * v2.x) + (v1.y * v2.y) + (v1.z * v2.z) + (v1.w * v2.w);
}

$ nvcc -std=c++11 -arch=sm_52 -dc -Xptxas="-v" vdot.cu
ptxas info    : 0 bytes gmem
ptxas info    : Function properties for cudaDeviceGetAttribute
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z4vdotff
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Function properties for cudaOccupancyMaxActiveBlocksPerMultiprocessor
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z4vdot6float4S_
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Function properties for cudaMalloc
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Function properties for cudaGetDevice
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Function properties for _Z4vdot6float2S_
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Function properties for cudaOccupancyMaxActiveBlocksPerMultiprocessorWithFlags
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Function properties for cudaFuncGetAttributes
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
```

Here we have a separately compiled set of three `__device__` functions in a device object file. Running `cuobjdump` on it will emit a lot of output, but in it you will get a register count for each function:

```
$ cuobjdump -elf ./vdot.o

Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_52
code version = [1,7]
producer = cuda
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit
compressed

<---Snipped--->


.text._Z4vdotff
bar = 0 reg = 6 lmem=0  smem=0
0xfec007f1  0x001fc000  0x00570003  0x5c980780  
0x00470000  0x5c980780  0x00370004  0x5c680000  
0xffe007ff  0x001f8000  0x0007000f  0xe3200000  
0xff87000f  0xe2400fff  0x00070f00  0x50b00000
```

In the second line of the output for the device function `dot(float, float)`  you can see the function uses 6 registers. This is the only way I am aware of to examine device function register footprints.

Comment: I would have an additional question, related to the profiling of my code. I'm trying to use nvvp/nvprof but I only get the output for my global functions. Is there any tool, compiling flag, etc.. I should use to get the detailed profiling results for each device function called by my kernels? The only solution I came up with so far is to change the device functions into global ones and call them separately. Do you think is there a better strategy?

Comment: How about `cuobjdump -elf ./vdot.o | c++filt` ?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know when it was added but my CUDA 10 `cuobjdump` has the `-res-usage` flag which shows something like this:

```
$ cuobjdump -res-usage .../cuda_compile_1_generated_VisualOdometry.cu.o

Fatbin elf code:
================
arch = sm_61
code version = [1,7]
producer = cuda
host = linux
compile_size = 64bit
identifier = /home/mad/automy-system/vision/src/VisualOdometry.cu

Resource usage:
 Common:
  GLOBAL:0 CONSTANT[3]:24
 Function _Z17vo_compute_systemPfS_P6float4S_jS0_S0_f:
  REG:39 STACK:32 SHARED:168 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:404 CONSTANT[2]:80 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
 Function _Z13vo_pre_filterP6float4PfPjPK5uint2iijff:
  REG:16 STACK:0 SHARED:8 LOCAL:0 CONSTANT[0]:372 TEXTURE:0 SURFACE:0 SAMPLER:0
```